# I'm trying to simplify with linq a statement that takes 2 lists of numbers and subtracts the first one from the second one

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I'm trying to simplify, with linq, and hopefully make cheaper, a statement that takes 2 lists of numbers and subtracts the first one from the second one. I have something that works but I think it could be cleaner and more efficient.

```
double[] main = _mainPower.Select(i => i.Decibels).ToArray();
double[] reference = _referencePower.Select(i => i.Decibels).ToArray();

List<double> amplitudeList = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < main.Count(); i++)
{
     if (!double.IsNaN(main[i] - reference[i]))
     {
          amplitudeList.Add(main[i] - reference[i]);
     }
}

 return amplitudeList;
```

If I have 2 lists List1 = {8,5,3} and List2 = {5,2,1} the list returned would be {3,3,2}
I have tried

```
return _mainPower.Select(i => i.Decibels - _referencePower.Select(a => a.Decibels));
```

but it obviously does not work. Is there a way to turn my function into a nice linq query? One thing that I haven't allowed for is if the lists are 2 different sizes. If the sizes are different then the longer list should be trimmed from the end to make them the same as the smaller one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

--EDIT--

Thanks for the help I used the post from StriplingWarrior to get what I needed.

```
_mainPower.Zip(_referencePower, (v1, v2) => v1.Decibels - v2.Decibels).Where(i => !double.IsNaN(i));
```

Comment: Look at [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx).

Comment: Wouldn't the returned list in your example be 3,3,2?

Comment: Yes, my bad. That's why I need the computer to do it for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do:

```
return _mainPower.Zip(_referencePower,(v1, v2) => v1-v2)
```

Comment: This is perfect. I just made 2 small changes and it works perfectly. I will post it in my question now. Thank you.